# Remove project from Google Developer Console

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a project listed on my Google Developer Console that I have no idea how it got there. I can't seem to delete it because it said I'm not the owner of the project. There is also $9.91 listed in the charges section, will I be charged for it? Also, how do I remove it completely from my console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have been added to that project with permission level of '[Can View](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/access)'. Since you're not the owner of the project, of course you will not be charged for any fees associated with this project.

In order to be removed from the project, you will need to go to the project and click on 'Permissions' option, then check who is or are the owners of the project. Finally try to contact the owner of that project to remove you from this project.

Comment: I was part of the group because of some google group I joined. I removed myself and it's gone from my console. Thanks!